# simplecaptcha image only served after reload

Tags: java, servlets, captcha, simplecaptcha

I'm using [SimpleCaptcha](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net) to secure our contact form. It works well, *but only after reloading the page*.

The Servlet is `nl.captcha.servlet.StickyCaptchaServlet`, so it should not change the image after reloads. But when first opening the page the image is just not loaded. However, after reloading everything works fine.

**the web.xml**

The captcha is served by an application running at `/services`.

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>captcha</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>nl.captcha.servlet.StickyCaptchaServlet<servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>captcha</servlet>
    <url-pattern>/captcha.png</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**the html**

```
<img src="/services/captcha.png">
```

**the server**

I'm using `tomcat-7.0.34` on a `Windows 7 64bit` machine with `Java 1.7.0_07`.

**the question**

Why does the image only show up after a reload? Any ideas?

Comment: your `StickyCaptchaServlet` is configured to `/captcha.png` and you using in html page `/services/captcha.jpg` is this real or just typo mistake? Do you have any other `Servlet` for this application? What is your `<load-on-startup>` configuration?

Comment: My fault, I copied it wrong... edited it in the question. I have two other servlets, both for contact forms, both checking if the captcha is solved. Currently there is no ``<load-on-startup>`` configuration.

Comment: try to add `<load-on-startup>` and set for your captcha server bigger value than for other servlets which are using that captcha

Comment: I tried it, but that doesn't work. Even if I access the servlet directly (at ``localhost:8080/services/captcha.png`` for example) it needs a reload to show the captcha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do this way to by pass what emka86 had said.

```
<img src="/services/captcha.png" style="display:none"> (Duplicate part to fix the issue)

<img src="/services/captcha.png"> (The actual one)
```

Hope this helps for any future developer out there.

Comment: While I ended up patching SimpleCaptcha myself (and tbh I forgot what I did exactly) this is a quite simple solution that I really like. Thanks!

Comment: @Nilindra, what if I am using **<img src="captchamage"  />** ??   Here "captchaImage" is mapped to a servlet in **web.xml** which return the actual captcha image.  I am also facing similar issue. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

there are several steps you can follow:

## 1> modify web.xml add your servlet that extends nl.captcha.servlet.StickyCaptchaServlet class

```
 <servlet>   
    <description></description>    
    <display-name>CustomCaptchaServlet</display-name>    
    <servlet-name>CustomCaptchaServlet</servlet-name>    
    <servlet-class>org.example.servlets.CustomCaptchaServlet</servlet-class>    
 </servlet>    
  <servlet-mapping>    
    <servlet-name>CustomCaptchaServlet</servlet-name>    
    <url-pattern>/CustomCaptchaServlet</url-pattern>    
  </servlet-mapping>
```

## 2> CustomCaptchaServlet.java

```
package org.example.servlets;    
import static nl.captcha.Captcha.NAME;    

import java.io.IOException;    

import javax.servlet.ServletException;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;    

import nl.captcha.Captcha;    
import nl.captcha.servlet.CaptchaServletUtil;    
import nl.captcha.servlet.StickyCaptchaServlet;    

public class CustomCaptchaServlet extends StickyCaptchaServlet {    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    

    /**
     * @see StickyCaptchaServlet#StickyCaptchaServlet()
     */
    public CustomCaptchaServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    

        String _width = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("width");    
        String _height = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("height");    
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();    
        Captcha captcha;    
        if (session.getAttribute(NAME) == null) {    
            captcha = new Captcha.Builder(Integer.parseInt(_width), Integer.parseInt(_height))    
            .addText()    
            .gimp()    
            .addBorder()    
                .addNoise()    
                .addBackground()    
                .build();    
            session.setAttribute(NAME, captcha);    
            CaptchaServletUtil.writeImage(response, captcha.getImage());    
            return;    
        }    
        captcha = (Captcha) session.getAttribute(NAME);    
        CaptchaServletUtil.writeImage(response, captcha.getImage());    
    }    


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {    

    }    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `web.xml` has `captcha.png` while the `HTML` is referring to `captcha.jpg`.

Does that solve the issue?

Comment: No, sorry. I just copied the html part wrong (it points to ``captcha.png``).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that StickyCaptchaServlet is creating new captcha image for session. When you make initial request to a page you have no session id so StickyCaptchaServlet cannot connect you to any image created for a particular session. 
 After first request main servlet create session for you and send you back some kind of `sessionId`. With next request (also reload) you send to server request with recevied previously `sessionId` so now your `StickyCaptchaServlet` is possible to collect captcha image for your session because it knows that you are in any session.

Do you understand this explanation? Will it be helpfull for you?

**Added after your question to resolve this problem.**

You can add to your web app class which will implements `HttpSessionListener`. Then, in method `sessionCreated` you can add request to `StickyCaptchaServlet` with just created `sessionId`. According to `StickyCaptchaServlet` doc You just have to invoke `doGet` method of it with passed sessionId key. After that - when browser on your page will request for url `/services/captcha.png` it should get as response image created and prepared just before it by your `HttpSessionListener` implementation.

Other way is to use cliend side scripting and after page is loaded, with no image at all, just reload it - as this internal reload, for example JavaScript, the browser will know sessionId and will pass it through the request for captcha image. By reload I mean only reload image, not the whole page.

Will any of those suggestions resolve your problem? Give me a feedback about it.

Comment: This explanation seems to adress my real problem. But is there any solution? (i.e. could I generate the session with a corresponding `sessionId` with the first page call?)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried client-side reloading of the image (re-setting the ``src`` attribute, adding a dummy value to force reload), but that does not work. Reloading the full page does not seem feasible to me. The ``HttpSessionListener`` thing sounds interesting, but I can't get it to call the ``doGet`` method of the ``StickyCaptchaServlet``.